# 1,1-Diphenylethylene subproduct/impurity

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, polymers, oxygen

I'm working with 1,1-diphenylethylene and I've observed that, if left at room temperature in the air atmosphere, a white insoluble powder forms. I'm unable so dissolve this powder in every solvent that I've tried (acetonitrile, acetone, ethyl acetate, hexane, water, etc), so I can't get an NMR spectrum. Moreover, I can't find any paper or information online about this subproduct/impurity.

Edit: The melting point of this powder is around 120-130 ºC.

1,1-Diphenylethylene has to be stored between 2-8 ºC, but the safety data sheet doesn't say that it has to be stored under an iner atmosphere. However, we have it stored under argon in the refrigerator and the impurity only appears when leftovers of 1,1-diphenylethylene are left outside in a vial, for example. Futhermore, I observed that 1,1-diphenylethylene is also oxidized to benzophenone when left outside.

[image: 1,1-Diphenylethylene]

Comment: Hmmm, a polymer?

Comment: Polymerisation seems very likely

Comment: Or possibly peroxide formation, An ATR FTir will give a spectrum that should help you. More information on purity, preparation method, storage details etc. would help us.  Does the compound arrive stored under N2?

Comment: @jimchmst I've added an edit with more information.

Comment: [This may be of help](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja0111131).